# removing deleted files from git

Tags: git, version-control

I renamed a file from file1-->file2 and git status shows:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    pathname/file1.xml
```

I did a git rm "pathname/file.xml" and it is staged for commit:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    pathname/file.xml
```

How do I remove this file?

after I commit and rebase , I am getting

`# Unmerged paths:`

```
 #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
 #   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)


added by us:        path/file1.xml
 no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Why are you rebasing after the commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Use `git commit` to commit the change.

**Longer answer:** It looks like you committed the new file already. If you want git see that the file moved, it might be better to amend your previous commit. Assuming that you have not made any other commits since you committed the new file, you can use the following command to do this:

```
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

Comment: after I commit and rebase , I am getting# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
# added by us:        path/file1.xml
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: @Sammys Try running `git rm path/file1.xml` again and do another commit.

Answer (score 1):

You've staged the removal, now commit it with `git commit`.